# Customizing UIButton Appearance in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton, swift2

I would like to customize a UIButton in Swift 2.0 that looks like the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y7Dy.png

- The gradient goes from: #b1ffb1 (light green) to #e7e7e7 (white/gray tint)
- A stroke: 2dp width, with a color of #999999 (solid gray)
- A Top Left/Right Corner Radius of 20dp

This button will turn into a gray gradient when pressed

- Pressed Gradient: #717171 (dark gray) to #acacac (lighter gray)
- Same Stroke
- Same Radius

---

My Attempts:

I have a lot of buttons in my app, several buttons will have the same appearance.  So I feel that it would be optimal to create individual classes for my customized buttons.

Here is my primitive attempt to replicate that button:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class CustomButtonTopGreen: UIButton {


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()   
    }
}
```

Which Yields:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF0sw.png

So my questions are:

- How can I incorporate hex color codes?
- How can I add in gradients?
- How may I customize individual corners?
- And how can I add an "On Pressed" view to this button?

I have done much research on the topic, but no luck.  I try to paste examples of code into my code, try to manipulate it to see if it would fit, but I still end up with errors.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: easiest way is to photoshop the image and use it as background image for the button!!!!

Comment: That is actually what I have now, the issue is that I want my buttons to look as identical as possible to the buttons in my Android Version (which was all done in code).  I'm not sure, maybe I'm a little obsessive compulsive over it.

Comment: y dont u just take screenshot your button in android, and convert it to image of required size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass UIButton and draw in drawRect creating a subclass like thus:

```
import UIKit


class CustomButtonTopGreen: UIButton {
    let cornerRadius:CGFloat = 20.0
    let borderLineWidth:CGFloat = 2.0
    var bezierPath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    var gradientLayer:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    var bottomLayer:UInt32 = 0

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        if self.state != UIControlState.Highlighted
        {
            self.drawBorder()

            let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradient.frame = self.bounds
            gradient.colors = [self.UIColorFromRGB(0xb1ffb1).CGColor, self.UIColorFromRGB(0xe7e7e7).CGColor]
            self.gradientLayer = gradient

            let mask = CAShapeLayer();
            mask.frame = self.bounds;

            mask.path = self.bezierPath.CGPath;
            mask.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
            mask.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
            gradient.mask = mask;

            let shape = CAShapeLayer();
            shape.path = self.bezierPath.CGPath
            shape.lineWidth = borderLineWidth
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
            shape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

            self.gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: bottomLayer)
            self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
            self.bottomLayer++

        }else{
            self.drawBorder()
            let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradient.frame = self.bounds
            gradient.colors = [self.UIColorFromRGB(0x717171).CGColor, self.UIColorFromRGB(0xacacac).CGColor]
            self.gradientLayer = gradient
            let mask = CAShapeLayer();
            mask.frame = self.bounds;

            self.bezierPath.lineWidth = 4.0
            mask.path = self.bezierPath.CGPath;
            mask.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
            mask.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
            gradient.mask = mask;

            let shape = CAShapeLayer();
            shape.path = self.bezierPath.CGPath
            shape.lineWidth = borderLineWidth
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
            shape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

            self.gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: bottomLayer)
            self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
            self.bottomLayer++
        }
    }

    func drawBorder(){
    let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: borderLineWidth, y: self.bounds.size.height-borderLineWidth))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: borderLineWidth, y: cornerRadius+borderLineWidth))
    path.addQuadCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: cornerRadius+borderLineWidth, y: borderLineWidth), controlPoint:CGPoint(x:borderLineWidth, y:borderLineWidth))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width-cornerRadius-borderLineWidth, y: borderLineWidth))
    path.addQuadCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width-borderLineWidth, y: cornerRadius+borderLineWidth), controlPoint: CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width-borderLineWidth, borderLineWidth))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width-borderLineWidth, y: self.bounds.size.height-borderLineWidth))
    path.closePath()
    path.lineWidth = borderLineWidth
    self.bezierPath = path
}

    func UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {

            self.setNeedsDisplay()

        }
    }


}
```

You should figure out a better way of replacing the normal gradientLayer with the highlighted gradientLayer, but it works as is.

Comment: This works well!  Although there is one little problem I have with it: when I run the code, the strokes on the sides of the button look a little wonky.  I can't tell if it's just the Xcode simulator or not (I have tried a bunch of them, but gave me the same result).  Here's what it looks like for me: http://i.imgur.com/Z2T8ppl.png I feel like the side strokes should be buffed out a px or 2

Comment: hmmm strange, the code is spitting out a few "separator" errors  http://i.imgur.com/gi5QiAd.png  I've tried tossing in the suggested commas, but it doesn't seem like Swift likes it

Comment: I guess I didn't paste it correctly. It was missing a ")" and the bottom half of the method wasn't updated. I've updated. Please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Looks good now!  I accepted the answer!  Out of curiosity, if I were to make the button with bottom corners instead, how should I manipulate your code?

Comment: You only need to change the drawBorder function. Look at the way the path is drawn. In iOS the greater the y value the more down screen the point. It starts in the bottomLeftCorner, adds a line up to where the top left cornerRadius starts, draws the corner, draws the top line to the next cornerRadius, draws that corner and so on. To have the cornerRadiuses on the bottom. Start in the top left corner path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:borderLineWidth,y:borderLineWidth)), add a straight line to top right corner path.addLineToPoint(….) then trace the rest with quad curves at the rounded corners.

Comment: I got it!  Thank you.  Kind of reminds me of G-code, so this was very intuitive!  Thanks again!